# Is there a way in visual studio code to type and run python code directly into the terminal?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, spyder

I am a novice programmer and I am quite used to using Spyder, mainly because my first programming experience was MATLAB, and Spyder is quite similar to that. However, I love a lot of the features in VScode, and was wondering if I am able to type python code directly into the terminal and run it, similar to MATLAB and Spyder.

Another quick question, is there a quicker way to run a python script than right clicking the file and clicking "Run Python file in terminal"?

Comment: Do you mean 'Run Python file in terminal' option? There's green button on the top-right of your window.

Comment: Yeah! If you want to enter python directly, just open up the integrated terminal! If you press `Ctrl+Shift+\`` you should be able to create a new terminal. You can toggle the terminal by using `Ctrl+\``. To run python from the file, just press `Ctrl+Alt+N`.

Comment: @ArvinKushwaha By pressing Ctrl+Shift+`  , it opens up a new terminal, but I am unable to type code directly into that and run it, if i try run `print('hi')`, it claims `"bash: syntax error near unexpected token 'hi'' `. I am unsure of the problem because I am quite new to this :(

Comment: Yeah, so when you open the terminal up, you have to type in `python` to open the python interpreter. From there, you can run code line by line, i.e. `print("hi")`, etc

Comment: @ArvinKushwaha Awesome cheers! As I said I'm a novice and I've never used VScode, I didn't realise the 'Terminal' in VScode is the same as the 'terminal' that comes with the computer somehow :( Cheers!